# Powershell - Compare two csv rows and write the result in the third

Tags: powershell, csv, compare

I have two csv columns, I need to compare these two columns and write the result in the third (Result).

> "Line","Path","Result"
>
> "RETENTION_LEVEL 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1","C:\Veritas\NetBackup\db\class\policy-v-\schedule\cum\info",

how to make the variable of the third column settable?

```
#Write retention and policy in a csv file. 
$file="C:\Users\toto\schedules.csv"
#Write analysis results in a final csv.
$finalFile="C:\Users\toto\bad_retention.csv"
#query to find information based on the retention level and policy + export in the csv
$find=Get-ChildItem "C:\Veritas\NetBackup\db\class\" -recurse | Select-String -pattern "RETENTION_LEVEL" | Select line,path,@{Expression={$_.result};Label="Result";} | Export-CSV $file –NoTypeInformation

        (Import-Csv $file -Delimiter ',')

        ForEach-Object{
            if(($_.line -match "RETENTION_LEVEL 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1") -and ($_.path -match "-v-"))
            {
             $_.result="BAD RETENTION"
             echo $_result;
            }
            else
            {
             $_.result="OK";
             echo $_result;
            }
        } | Export-CSV $finalFile –NoTypeInformation
```

> ```
> Property 'result' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
> At C:\Users\toto\Documents\bad_retention.ps1:28 char:17
> +              $_. <<<< result="OK";
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (result:String) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Veritas\NetBackup\db\class\" -recurse |
 Select-String -pattern "RETENTION_LEVEL" |
 Select line,path,@{
  Label = 'result'
  Expression = {('OK','BAD RETENTION')[($_.line -match "RETENTION_LEVEL 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1") -and ($_.path -match "-v-")]}
  } |
  Export-CSV $file –NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

With the syntax below it works":

```
Expression = {('OK','BAD RETENTION')[($_.line -eq "RETENTION_LEVEL 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1")]}
```